# Sox returns some value but StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() returns empty

Tags: c#, console-application, sox

```
try
{
        string filename = "E:\\sox-14-4-0\\mysamplevoice.wav";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\sox-14-4-0\\sox.exe ";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = filename + " -n stat";
        p.Start();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
}
```

The output is always empty. When I run that `sox` command in command prompt I could get a response like:

```
E:\sox-14-4-0>sox mysamplevoice.wav -n stat
Samples read:             26640
Length (seconds):      3.330000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.515625
Minimum amplitude:    -0.734375
Midline amplitude:    -0.109375
Mean    norm:          0.058691
Mean    amplitude:     0.000122
RMS     amplitude:     0.101146
Maximum delta:         0.550781
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.021387
RMS     delta:         0.041831
Rough   frequency:          526
Volume adjustment:        1.362
```

When running the same command in C# I get the same result but value of "output" is empty.

Comment: i didn't know, im new n i thought some1 has wrongly edited it. Apologize for that and will not do it again.

Comment: Users with a ♦ at the end of their names are moderators here, so you should usually not revert their actions. If you have questions/don't understand why an edit was made, you can "ping" the editor with a comment containing @TheEditorsNickname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure sox.exe writes to STDOUT and not to STDERR ?

you could try reading the data using the `OutputDataReceived` event instead.

```
string filename = "E:\\sox-14-4-0\\mysamplevoice.wav";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\sox-14-4-0\\sox.exe ";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = filename + " -n stat";

p.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
p.ErrorDataReceived += process_ErrorDataReceived;

p.Start();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();


void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;
}

void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried your code. i get an exception error "Standard error has not been redirected". This happens when the debug reaches p.BeginErrorReadLine();

Comment: add `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;`

Comment: Works, but i get only first line
"Samples read:             26640"
How to read all the lines?

Comment: This is where we draw the "Homework" line. Go and do some independent research

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem too. Why does SoX write to StandardError?!

In case someone else runs into this problem too, the solution to the original question could just be adding 2 lines

```
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; // <-- this
...
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
if(output == "") output = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // <-- and this
```